# Several Tables in Cache - best way to do a pipeline of joins for each entry in file?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am prototyping a spark Sql process in which I've created around 7-8 cached tables and registered them as temporary tables which are derived by several joins  for some huge RDBMS models files so that i can reference smaller chunks of data rather than a heavy sql for one record.I have given an example below with each having a minimum of 100-200MM rows.

```
JavaRDD<peopleObject> readFile = sc.textFile("some file").map("people object");


DataFrame schema1= sqlContext.createDataFrame() 
registerTemptable
cachetable 
count*

DataFrame schema2= sqlContext.sql(...) '
registerTempTable
cacheTable count* 
.... 
.... 
DataFrame schema9 = sqlcontext.createDataFrame() 
cachetable 
count*
```

Pseudo code example:  If input file column1=XXX or column2-SSS the join to schema1 else join schema2 and schema3 sequentially finally create output

Now I will have several input files which need to access these tables in a series like pipeline. Can some one suggest me a cleaner way to achieve this? Does joining data ahead and caching them will help the huge data in input files achieve better performance? Let me know if you need more information